# Importing a subversion repository

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, svn, flashbuilder4

I'm having problems: I create a new repository in Subclipse that points to a URL. When I check out the code and it creates a Flex Builder project, I am getting errors that relate to issues with the .actionscriptProperties and .flexProperties files.

So, I was told to just create a new FB project and point the src folder to where SVN is on my machine.

I'm new at this. But I'm guessing that until I do something like import my repository....it's nowhere on my machine. But when I imported it, it appeared to try and take every existing FB project I had and add it to SVN. That's not what I want.

How do I do this right? What am I missing?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. right click in the navigator, new -> other
2. Under SVN, select Checkout projects from    SVN
3. Select the location of your repo with the FB project, hit next
4. there should only be one radio button available, if not, you **didn't** select the correct trunk location with the project files
5. Check "Check out HEAD revision", depth: fully recursive, uncheck ignore externals, check allow unversioned obstructions
6. click "finish"

If it complains about anything, let me know what the error is. You may have a different default, for instance, if the project was configured using "default SDK" and the project creator's default SDK was different than your default SDK you'd get errors.

Comment: Thank you, it appears it was a different SDK than I had. However, do you know how to set the 'src' directory instead of importing the whole project. Can that even be done?

Comment: The best way is to add all your project files to "ignore" except the source directory. That way each developer can have their own eclipse settings, etc. But that requires the consent of all other developers and the SVN maintainer. Another way is to create a project, then use TortoiseSVN to checkout just the source folder, but you won't have SVN integrated into eclipse.